# attr.checked not working on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an element dynamically that is using `[attr.checked]`

.ts

```
public value = true;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  let testElemet = let testElemet = `<input type="checkbox" [attr.checked]="` + this.value + `? 'checked' : null"/>`;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testElemet;
}
```

.html

```
<div id=test>
 <!-- element is created here but is not checked -->
</div>

<!-- this element is checked as it should -->
<input type="checkbox" [attr.checked]="value ? 'checked' : null"/>
```

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Angular has its own template syntax for dynamically generating HTML. Use that. Don't try to use `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work this way in Angular, there is no `$compile` service to compile dynamic as in AngularJS.

What you're looking for is dynamic components loading, check this official guide https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.